# Get User Selection in Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a button inside a popupwindow that when clicked initializes an alertdialog with a list from which the user can choose from. I'm stuck trying to get the string value of the selected item from the list. I'm trying to get the item and then change the description text on the button to reflect the user's selection.

```
countryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> countryAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.countries_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(MakeQuestion.this)
        .setTitle("Country")
        .setAdapter(countryAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //String countryResult = countryList.get(which);
            //countryButton.setText(countryResult);
            dialog.dismiss();
            }
            }).create().show();
    }

});
```

Comment: @Tanis.7x I tried to get the which from the countrylist and then toString it. But it get gave me a missing reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ArrayAdapter.getItem() method. And if it isn´t just a copy paste mistake, don´t forget the @Override annotation. But what do You mean with "missing reference error"?

```
countryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> countryAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.countries_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(MakeQuestion.this)
    .setTitle("Country")
    .setAdapter(countryAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        String countryResult = countryAdapter.getItem(which);//use this getItem() method
        countryButton.setText(countryResult);
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
        }).create().show();
}

});
```

Comment: Works with an edit that involves changing ArrayAdapter type from CharSequence to String.